Storing tree structures where a node can be in multiple trees
I am trying to find a way to build a model in Entity Framework to represent Courses and Lessons, where each course can have multiple Courses and lessons within it. However i also want to make it so lessons and courses can be used in multiple places. In essence I see this as multiple tree structures where a Lesson or a Course can be in multiple trees as a Node.
So far my idea is to create an abstract Class for the LearningItem which both Lesson and Course can inherit and then make a class for the relationship, something like this:
public abstract class LearningItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LearningItem>? Parents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LearningItem>? Children { get; set; }
}

public class LearningItemRelationships
{
    public LearningItem AncestorLearningItem { get; set; }
    public LearningItem? ParentLearningItem { get; set; }
    public LearningItem? LearningItem { get; set; }
    public int OrderInParent { get; set; }
    public int Depth { get; set; }
}

But i cannot figure out how to set this up in OnModelCreate, or if this is a feasible approach at all.
does someone have suggestions for this?

You can use ids instead of objects and retrieve entities by ids.
